# How to display a DatePicker popup in .NET MAUI project?

Tags: c#, .net-maui

For Xamarin projects to display Date picker in popup I used [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs), but it is not compatible with .NET MAUI.

Is there a port or something like this for .NET MAUI?

If no, how can I display a date popup for a .NET MAUI project?

Comment: So you want your app to have a [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/datepicker)?

Comment: @FreakyAli I want to show already expanded datepicker in a modal popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided, The newest version of the `Acr.UserDialogs` package has supported the .net maui.

And you can check the package owner's sample which shows how to use `Acr.UserDialogs`  version 8.0.1.

Sample link: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/tree/master/sample/Sample

Comment: Thank you, I will check the source code of the project. If it works, I will mark this answers as a solution.

Comment: For Xamarin project, for Android, it is required to call `UserDialogs.Init()` to initialize the library. For [MAUI sample](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/sample/Sample/MauiProgram.cs), the initialization part moved to MauiProgram. But it causes error, saying that initialization was not done properly: https://i.imgur.com/5ebAFnP.jpg

I tried to call initialization part in old fashioned (Xamarin) way, it compiled, but error still persists. I will investigate this issue further, and in case I find something I will post here.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Did you try to clone the sample to your visual studio directly? @Rafael

Comment: Yes, I cloned the whole repo, and opened it in Visual Studio. In Visual Studio I set Sample as a startup project and ran it.

Comment: Although there are compilation issues with nuget package version 8.0.1 I am marking your answer as solution. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Hello I'm having the same issue as @Rafael. It builds but then fails with the same error.

Comment: @Stargazer Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74568948/12576990

Comment: Thanks, @Rafael, appreciated.
However, I was doing exactly that. My issue, however, was the way we were porting code from XF to MAUI. 
We were setting up the Navigation page in App.Xaml.cs and the bound view model was getting a UserDialogs instance. That happens before the initialization on ApplicationCreate. Moving things around fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To init UserDialogs correctly in Android, to also provide UserDialogs with DependencyInjection (ConstructorInjection) i do it in my MainApplication.cs

```
protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    UserDialogs.Init(this);
    return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}
```

In this case you can also apply UserDialogs to your DependencyInjection service like

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);
```

in your MauiProgram.cs.

So the ConfigureLifecycleEvents isn't needed anymore and you can also avoid this ugly #if pattern ;)

Comment: I put "builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);" in my maui project, got the exception "CS0103 The name 'UserDialogs' does not exist in the current context". Is this normal, any repo to share, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use .net6 version of Acr.UserDialogs package, I have to initialize it in `MauiProgram` instead of `MainActivity`.

My `MauiProgram` class looks like that, note the `ConfigureLifecycleEvents` part. It is relevant to the subject.

```cs
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder.UseMauiApp<App>().ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                      // configuring fonts here, (not related to the subject)
            })
            .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnApplicationCreate(app => UserDialogs.Init(app)));
#endif
            })
            // other useXXXXX() calls (not related to the subject)


            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
```